# White text on badges is impossible to read

Tags: bug, status-completed

when viewing the site in Firefox 3.5.15 the white text on the badges is almost the same color of the badge making the text of the badge impossible to read as seen on the screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: Likewise for Opera under Windows XP - I'm sure it looks fine on a Mac though. :)

Comment: Can't see it on Internet Explorer 9

Comment: Oh wait, that's cos it's just a screenshot :P lol I need sleep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have put in a fix. The reason is because older browsers don't support CSS3 gradient, and I forgot to put in a fallback background color, that's why the badges looked weird to you. The fix should be in the next deployment. I also left out the gradient CSS for Opera because I've been experiencing some glitches with some of the CSS3 elements in Opera lately.

Comment: Roughly how often are the deployments? Also - I presume the fix applies to both the parent and this *meta* site? I see the badges fine on parent, just not on the meta site.

Comment: @Cyclops, I have fixed the Meta badges. The change should be in the next day or two.

Comment: Thanks, it just appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you seeing this? I can't duplicate it in Firefox 3.6.x (also, why are you using Firefox 3.5 and not 3.6 -- there are MASSIVE JavaScript performance regressions in 3.5 that are fixed in 3.6.. really not recommended.)